# Problems when turning on plugged in laptop

Tags: dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7000 laptop and for some unknown reason the monitor doesn't turn on but my keyboard lights up. The only that this happens is when the battery is full and still plugged in. Other than that I don't have any clue why it won't turn on.

Comment: Did you try to plug an external monitor and see if you can see something ?

Comment: I don't have a spare monitor that I could use